# Convert R data.frames to XML with nice layout in notepad

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to output by R dataframes into XML format and be able to open and read them in Notepad or Notepad++.

I can convert them with no issues using the following code:

```
data <- iris
xml <- xmlTree() 
xml$addNode("table", close=FALSE) 
for (rr in 1:nrow(data)) { 
  xml$addTag("row", close=FALSE) 
  for (cc in names(data)) { 
    xml$addTag(cc, data[rr, cc]) 
  } 
  xml$closeTag() 
} 
xml$closeNode()

saveXML(xml, file = "Test.xml", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

However when I open the resulting file in Notepad or Notepad++ if looks a bit like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table><row><Sepal.Length>5.1</Sepal.Length><Sepal.Width>3.5</Sepal.Width><Petal.Length>1.4</Petal.Length><Petal.Width>0.2</Petal.Width><Species>setosa</Species></row><row>...
```

Is there a way to incorporate spaces into the code so it looks like this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <table>
     <row>
       <Sepal.Length>5.1</Sepal.Length>
       <Sepal.Width>3.5</Sepal.Width>
       <Petal.Length>1.4</Petal.Length>
       <Petal.Width>0.2</Petal.Width>
       <Species>setosa</Species>
     </row>
     <row>...
```

It does look nicely spaced when I open it using Internet Explorer, but if I copy and paste that it also copies and pastes the little '+' and '-' signs which is annoying to have to then manually remove, especially if my dataset is huge.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: You could try `write_xml` from the `xml2` package instead. It indented the XML output on the small test data that I tried.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get it to work though, it says: `Error in UseMethod("write_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'write_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDOM', 'XMLOutputStream', 'namedList', 'list', 'vector')"`  An I can't seem to find what class my data needs to be in for this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that indentation serves only to make XML documents more human-readable. It makes no difference to how it is processed computationally and if your "dataset is huge", you probably don't need to inspect it visually.

`xml2::write_xml` seems to generated indented output:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr) # for the pipes (%>%)

"<a><b>1</b></a>" %>%
  read_xml() %>%
  write_xml("out.xml")
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
  <b>1</b>
</a>
```

You may also like to look at the [rio](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rio/vignettes/rio.html) package. It makes format conversion easier. Unfortunately the XML written out by its converter is not indented...so you would need to read it back in and run it through `write_xml` again:

```
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(rio)

export(iris, "out.xml") %>% 
  read_xml("out.xml") %>% 
  write_xml("out.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks, thats good info :) Unfortunately write_xml doesn't work for me. When I try with the xml object I created above i gives the error `Error in UseMethod("write_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'write_xml' applied to an object of class "c('XMLInternalDOM', 'XMLOutputStream', 'namedList', 'list', 'vector')"` Any ideas on what form the xml object needs to be in for it to work?

Comment: It needs to be class `xml_document` or `xml_node`, typically generated by `xml2::read_xml`. I suggested using `rio` as an alternative to your code for XML generation.

Comment: you're a legend, works like a charm and is much easier than my way :) thanks!